# flutter Admob LoadAdError(No ad config)

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have a error when I used admob.
It gives an error even though I have done all the settings. `LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})`

Error

[image: 1]

AndroidManifest configuration

[image: 2]

I made the settings but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Under `android\app\build.gradle` have you added the following code?
After `fluter{source '../..'}`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
}
```